# Manipular String C#

Tags: c#

Eu tenho strings que chegam assim:

```
"Cadastro,Novo"
"Cadastro,Editar"
"Cadastro,Excluir"
"Cadastro,Morfar"
"Cadastro,Etc"

"Entidade,Novo"
"Entidade,Editar"
"Entidade,Excluir"
"Entidade,Morfar"
"Entidade,Etc"
```

E tenho 2 Colunas que pretendo preencher:

```
Coluna1 | Coluna2
```

A ordem deve ser a seguinte:

```
Coluna1 = Cadastro 
Coluna2 = "Novo,Editar,Excluir,OqueVim"
```

Mas não posso repetir o valor Cadastro quando irei concatenar os valores na Coluna2.

Alguém pode me explicar como fazer isso?

Meu código está assim:

Classe para Adicionar os valores final

```
public class ListaFinal
{
  public string valor1 { get; set; }
  public string valor2 { get; set; }
}
```

Código:

```
 var listaFinal = new List<ListaFinal>();
      var adiciona = new List<string>();
      adiciona.Add("Cadastro.Novo");
      adiciona.Add("Cadastro.Editar");
      adiciona.Add("Cadastro.Deletar");
      adiciona.Add("Cadastro.Excluir");
      adiciona.Add("Cadastro.ALGO");

      adiciona.Add("Entidade.Item1");
      adiciona.Add("Entidade.Enti");
      adiciona.Add("Entidade.dade");
      adiciona.Add("Entidade.outro");
      adiciona.Add("Entidade.test");

      string coluna1 = "";
      string coluna2 = "";
      foreach (var x in adiciona)
      {
        var aux = "";
        coluna2 = x.Split('.')[1];
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(coluna1))
        {
          coluna1 = x.Split('.')[0];

          listaFinal.Add(new ListaFinal
          {
            valor1 = coluna1,
            valor2 = coluna2
          });
        }
        else
        {
          aux = x.Split('.')[0];
          if (aux != coluna1)
          {
            coluna1 = aux;

            listaFinal.Add(new ListaFinal
            {
              valor1 = coluna1,
              valor2 = coluna2
            });

          }

        }
        coluna1 = coluna1;
      };
```

Resultado final: 2 itens na lista, com os campos antes da vírgula sem repetir, mas não tenho concatenado os valores após a vírgula.

Comment: Voce quer dizer que a cada valor antes da virgula voce quer ter todos os valores que aparecem para ele depois da virgula?

Comment: Sim, mas sem repetir o valor que está antes da virgula

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `String.Split` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/b873y76a(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var strings = suaString.Split(',');
```

No caso, `strings` é um `Array`.

Conforme pedido em comentário, para usar na forma de dicionários (ou mapas), em C# funciona da seguinte forma:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, string[]>();
var subarray = new string[strings.Length - 1];
Array.Copy(strings, 1, subarray, 0, dict.Length - 1)
dict.Add(strings[0], subarray);
```

---

EDIT

Depois que o autor da pergunta colocou o código, modifiquei para o seguinte:

```
        var listaFinal = new Dictionary<String, List<String>>();
        var adiciona = new List<string>();
        adiciona.Add("Cadastro.Novo");
        adiciona.Add("Cadastro.Editar");
        adiciona.Add("Cadastro.Deletar");
        adiciona.Add("Cadastro.Excluir");
        adiciona.Add("Cadastro.ALGO");

        adiciona.Add("Entidade.Item1");
        adiciona.Add("Entidade.Enti");
        adiciona.Add("Entidade.dade");
        adiciona.Add("Entidade.outro");
        adiciona.Add("Entidade.test");

        foreach (var x in adiciona)
        {
            var s = x.Split('.').ToList();
            if (!listaFinal.ContainsKey(s.First())) listaFinal[s.First()] = new List<string>();
            listaFinal[s.First()].AddRange(s.Skip(1).ToList());
        };

        foreach (var chaveValor in listaFinal)
        {
            // chaveValor.Key contém o elemento "Cadastro" ou "Entidade".
            // chaveValor.Value contém uma lista de strings que é o valor depois do  ponto de cada elemento.
        }
```

Comment: Cigano, eu nao sei C#, entao voce pode expandir sua resposta para que voce armazene cada `strings[1:]` em um mapa ou semelhante do C# com `strings[0]`?

Comment: Saquei. Vou expandir.

Comment: Eu fiz um código aqui, ele me retorna sem repetir, mas não concatena o valor após a virgula, ele fica substituindo

Comment: @Rod Pode por favor colocar esse código na pergunta?

Comment: Editei agora a resposta, espero que de para entender

Comment: Ele só pegou o ultimo valor :/

Comment: @Rod Verdade. Arrumei.